# Install Ubuntu alongside windows 7 is not working

Tags: windows-7, system-installation

I am attempting to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with a USB drive on my laptop which has Windows 7 installed (as well as HP QuickWeb if that makes a differences). I want to keep Windows 7. So, I followed the instructions, booted to my flash drive, and began the installation process.

The first thing that I noticed was that the screen shown was not the same as that of the tutorial page. **The following screen was not shown**

[image]

Instead, I get this screen:

[image: http://imgur.com/WPaAJ8x]

Based on the descriptions, I choose to "Install inside Windows" After this, my computer turned off, and began to restart. Upon restarting, Windows 7 started. I was not asked for the size of the partition, nor anything else.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: @user68186 Thank you for your comment. My goal is to install the operating systems along side one another, however the option is not shown when I boot from the USB.

Comment: @user68186 Here is a picture of the screen. http://imgur.com/WPaAJ8x Note that I made an error: it is three options. Under the second option, there are two more options.

Comment: So how would I go about fixing this?